Leaflet with vue3 composition api, TypeError: fitBounds is not a function
I am using vue3, leaflet and vue-leaflet with composition api.
I want to zoomIn the map when multi markers were added.
But when I use mapRef.value?.fitBounds(bounds, { padding: [50,50] }) ,
it will show => TypeError: mapRef.value?.fitBounds is not a function. 
I found many answer if I use option api.
Is there an answer for composition api or other better ways?
<template>
  <l-map
    ref="mapRef"
    :zoom="zoom"
    :center="center"
    :use-global-leaflet="false"
  >
    <l-tile-layer url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png" />
    <l-marker
      v-for="(item, i) in markers"
      :key="i"
      :lat-lng="[item.LAT, item.LNG]"
    />
  </l-map>
</template>


JS: <script setup>

const mapRef = ref(null)
const zoom = ref(9.5)
const center = ref([22.7, 120.25])

const markers = computed(() => data.map(item => {
  return {
    ID: parseInt(item.ID),
    DTYPE: item.DTYPE,
    LAT: parseFloat(item.LAT),
    LNG: parseFloat(item.LNG)
  }
}))

watch(markers, () => {
  if (markers.value.length > 0 && mapRef.value) {
    const minLat = Math.min(...markers.value.map(marker => marker.LAT))
    const maxLat = Math.max(...markers.value.map(marker => marker.LAT))
    const minLng = Math.min(...markers.value.map(marker => marker.LNG))
    const maxLng = Math.max(...markers.value.map(marker => marker.LNG))

    const boundsObj = L.latLngBounds(L.latLng(minLat, minLng), L.latLng(maxLat, maxLng))

    // center
    const centerObj = boundsObj.getCenter()
    center.value = [centerObj.lat, centerObj.lng]

    // zoom
    // console.log(mapRef.value) // Proxy
    mapRef.value?.fitBounds(boundsObj, { padding: [50, 50] })
  }
})

I had saw an answer in another question.
It said bounds in fitBounds(bounds) is an array not an latLngBounds object.
But when I used typescipt it said the array type is not allowed.

Please, provide a way to reproduce, this needs to be debugged. In your code  mapRef.value is expected to be an object that has fitBounds method https://github.com/vue-leaflet/vue-leaflet/blob/db34dff79cc62bc6fa51357e953e9bcf55725c94/src/components/LMap.vue#L339 . "But when I used typescipt it said" - please, don't retell errors but list them as is. Lib internals like fitBounds aren't typed and providing an array shouldn't be a problem, it's accessing unknown method that will require it to be typed. However, TypeError is runtime and not compilation error and these problems are likely unrelated
